# Applying a function to 2 stl vectors

Tags: c++, stl

I'm currently trying to learn how to effectively use the STL part of c++. Say there are 2 vectors of the same type of equal length that need to be transformed into another vector of the same length by applying some operator, is there a good way to do this using the functionality of the STL?

Here's some pseudocode for what I'm trying to do:

```
vector<T> a;
vector<T> b;
vector<T> result;

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){
    result.at(i) = a.at(i)  op  b.at(i);
}
```

where "op" is some operator that is defined for type T.

Comment: You're right to learn to use STL algorithms, C++0x (and lambdas) will probably popularize their use.

Comment: Good to hear as I figure that learning the STL well is crucial to gaining c++ proficiency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to do some checking on sizes, but generally you can use `std::transform`.

E.g. (for `+` - `<functional>` contains class templates for function objects for this and other binary operators)

```
std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<T>() );
```

You need to ensure that `b.size() >= a.size()` and `result.size() >= a.size()`. If `result` starts out empty then you can use a `back_insert_iterator` to fill it without having to resize the container first.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for. In this case result is starting as empty so what is the correct syntax for using back_insert_iterator ?

Comment: Ok I think I figured this out,
#include <iterator>
then use:
std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), back_inserter(result), std::plus<T>() );   Thanks for the good answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use std::transform :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/